# How to combine Red-Yellow-Blue colored textures?

Tags: texturing, shaders

I'm trying to recreate a bot from game 'Descent'..I found a dump with the textures, but it's using some kind of mix to get the texture colors in-game.

The bot I'm making is green, but combining the yellow and blue texture doesn't get close to what it's supposed to look like, see the blender screenshot. I also tried the MixRGB node.

Any ideas on how these colors should be combined? For reference, I also added the colors of the other bots in the game.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You have the color space set to linear on the lower texture but sRGB on the upper.  Even if the files are color files, you need to use the same color space for each.

Comment: I'm not sure about the details of your project or images, but you could always add a Hue/Saturation node between the image texture (any color) and the input of whatever shader you're using. You can change the color by adjusting the hue value.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I'll give that a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a glance, I don't think these are color information maps. Given that the yellow has no texture and the red has the inverse of the blue, I would guess red and blue are specular maps and yellow is a bump map. I think you're missing the actual color texture

Comment: Interesting thought, but I never saw any bump mapping in this game..its basically a bunch of simple geometry running on a pentium 1 in DOS, no 3d acceleration etc

Comment: I did a extract of the resources myself and the missing green texture was indeed there!